# An exception occured when trying append "pending_xref" node to signode

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docutils

I'm trying append **pending_xref** node to *signode* of **handle_signature** function, but getting exception in docutils script:

> Exception occurred:
>     File "\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\docutils\nodes.py", line 569, in __getitem__
>
> > return self.children[key] **IndexError: list index out of range**

My code:

```py
def handle_signature(self, sig, signode):
   if 'mod' in self.options:
      signode += nodes.Text(self.options['mod'] + ' ')
   signode += nodes.Text('Some text ')
   names, _, _ = Obj.parse_signature(sig)
   if names:
      ns = names.strip().split('.')
      for cl in ns:
         # because off this, i'm get an error
         signode += addnodes.pending_xref('', refdomain='mydomain',
         reftype='ahg', reftarget=cl, modname=None, classname=None)
   return sig
```

Everything is working without *+= addnode.pending_xref()* (and other nodes appends successfully, except this).

> In **nodes.py** when exception occures, index equals to 0 (but it's nothing tells me).

You can reproduce this with my script on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Yxb0U8CZ). For test just use the directive `.. sphinxtest:recipe:: TestRecipe`. In my case after `make html`, i'm getting the error above.

Full code:

```
import re

from docutils import nodes
from docutils.parsers import rst
from docutils.parsers.rst import directives

from docutils.statemachine import ViewList
from sphinx.locale import _
from sphinx.domains import Domain, Index, ObjType
from sphinx.domains.std import StandardDomain
from sphinx.roles import XRefRole
from sphinx.directives import ObjectDescription
from sphinx.util.docfields import DocFieldTransformer
from sphinx.util.nodes import make_refnode, nested_parse_with_titles
from sphinx import addnodes


class RecipeObject(ObjectDescription):
    has_content = True
    required_arguments = 1
    option_spec = {}
    final_argument_whitespace = False

    def run(self):
        # Default run function, but added: before_sig
        if ':' in self.name:
            self.domain, self.objtype = self.name.split(':', 1)
        else:
            self.domain, self.objtype = '', self.name
        self.indexnode = addnodes.index(entries=[])

        node = addnodes.desc()
        node.document = self.state.document
        node['domain'] = self.domain
        node['objtype'] = node['desctype'] = self.objtype
        node['noindex'] = noindex = ('noindex' in self.options)

        self.names = []  # type: List[unicode]
        signatures = self.get_signatures()
        for i, sig in enumerate(signatures):
            beforesignode = nodes.container(sig)
            signode = addnodes.desc_signature(sig, '')
            signode['first'] = False
            node.append(beforesignode)
            node.append(signode)
            self.before_sig(beforesignode)
            try:
                name = self.handle_signature(sig, signode)
            except ValueError:
                signode.clear()
                signode += addnodes.desc_name(sig, sig)
                continue
            if name not in self.names:
                self.names.append(name)
                if not noindex:
                    self.add_target_and_index(name, sig, signode)

        contentnode = addnodes.desc_content()
        node.append(contentnode)
        if self.names:
            self.env.temp_data['object'] = self.names[0]
        self.before_content()
        self.state.nested_parse(self.content, self.content_offset, contentnode)
        DocFieldTransformer(self).transform_all(contentnode)
        self.env.temp_data['object'] = None
        self.after_content()
        return [self.indexnode, node]

    def before_sig(self, signode):
        """
        Called before main ``signode`` appends
        """
        pass

    def handle_signature(self, sig, signode):
        signode += nodes.Text('recipe ')
        names = sig.strip().split('.')
        for nm in names:
            print(nm)
            signode += addnodes.pending_xref('', refdomain='sphinxtest', reftype='rec', 
                                            reftarget=nm, modname=None, classname=None)
        return sig

    def add_target_and_index(self, name, sig, signode):
        anchor = '{}-{}'.format(self.objtype, sig)
        full_name = self.get_full_name(name)
        if anchor not in self.state.document.ids:
            signode['names'].append(anchor)
            signode['ids'].append(anchor)
            signode['first'] = not self.names
            self.state.document.note_explicit_target(signode)

            objects = self.env.domaindata['sphinxtest']['objects']
            objects[name] = (self.env.docname, self.objtype, anchor)

        index_text = self.get_index_text(name)
        if index_text:
            self.indexnode['entries'].append(('single', index_text, full_name, full_name, None))

    def get_full_name(self, name):
        return '{}.{}'.format(self.objtype, name)

    def get_index_text(self, cls_name):
        name = _('{} (Recipe)').format(cls_name)
        return name


class RecipeDomain(Domain):
    name = 'sphinxtest'
    label = 'Test'

    roles = {
        'rec': XRefRole(),
    }

    object_types = {
        'recipe': ObjType(_('recipe'), 'rec', 'obj'),
    }

    directives = {
        'recipe': RecipeObject,
    }

    initial_data = {
        'objects': {}
    }

    def clear_doc(self, docname):
        for name, (doc, objtype, anchor) in self.data['objects'].copy().items():
            if doc == docname:
                del self.data['objects'][name]

    def get_objects(self):
        for name, (docname, objtype, anchor) in self.data['objects'].items():
            yield (name, name, objtype, docname, anchor, 1)

    def resolve_xref(self, env, fromdocname, builder,
                     typ, target, node, contnode):
        print('Resolving xref of target: ' + target)
        match = [(name, sig, typ, docname, anchor, prio)
                 for name, sig, typ, docname, anchor, prio
                 in self.get_objects() if sig == target]

        if len(match) > 0:
            print('Match = {}'.format(match))
            todocname = match[0][3]
            targ = match[0][4]

            refnode = make_refnode(builder, fromdocname, todocname, targ, contnode, targ)
            print('RefNode: {}'.format(refnode))

            return make_refnode(builder, fromdocname, todocname, targ, contnode, targ)

        return None

    def merge_domaindata(self, docnames, otherdata):
        pass

    def resolve_any_xref(self, env, fromdocname, builder, target, node, contnode):
        pass


def setup(app):
    app.add_domain(RecipeDomain)
    return {
        'version': '0.1',
        'parallel_read_safe': True,
        'parallel_write_safe': True,
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is the purpose of your code? How can we reproduce the problem?

Comment: @mzjn i'm making custom domain for sphinx. And the **handle_signature** function is defined in _Object_ class, what inherit _ObjectDescription_. I'm trying to append referenced text, and when you click on it, goes to the declaration of object node with name from parsed signature.

Comment: But I cannot run the code in the question. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @mzjn here is the code on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Yxb0U8CZ). Try to use directive for example: `.. sphinxtest:recipe:: TestRecipe`. And after making html, i'm getting an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding some text element as child:

```py
refnode = addnodes.pending_xref('', refdomain='mydomain', reftype='typ', reftarget=t, modname=None, classname=None)
refnode += nodes.Text('Title')
```